# I set geolocation permission in the manifest, but every page still asks to share location

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, geolocation, content-script

I'm using a content-script in a chrome extension that I'm writing. I included `geolocation` in my list of permissions, but on every webpage I still get asked if I want to share my location.

I thought if I set `geolocation` in the list of permissions, I would avoid this? Here's the relevant code from my `manifest.json`:

```
"permissions": ["geolocation"],
"content_scripts": [
 {
   "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
   "js": ["main.js"]
 }
]
```

And how I'm using it:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    console.log("latitude=" + position.coords.latitude +
    ", longitude=" + position.coords.longitude);
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are calling the geolocation from a content script, the context of the target page is used and the request looks like it's coming from the target page.  So each different domain must be authorized.  (Content scripts are essentially injected javascript with enhanced privileges.)

To avoid the need for domain-by-domain permission, call the geolocation API ([which is an HTML5 API, not a chrome.* API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_other.html)) from [an Event Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html).

Here's a complete extension that demonstrates the process:

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions":      ["geolocation"],
    "content_scripts":  [ {
        "js":               [   "main.js" ],
        "matches":          [   "<all_urls>" ]
    } ],
    "background": {
        "scripts":      ["eventPage.js"],
        "persistent":   false
    },
    "name":             "_Read browser location",
    "description":      "See SO Q 18307051. Scarf location without spamming warnings",
    "version":          "1"
}
```

**main.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage ( {command: "gimmeGimme"}, function (response) {
    console.log (response.geoLocation);
} );
```

**eventPage.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener (
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {

        if (request.command == "gimmeGimme") {

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (function (position) {
                sendResponse ( {
                    geoLocation: (
                          "latitude="    + position.coords.latitude
                        + ", longitude=" + position.coords.longitude
                    )
                } );
            } );
            return true; // Needed because the response is asynchronous
        }
    }
);
```